# Replace text from controller and put it inside property file

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Replace text from controller and put it inside property file

What  I have already:

My controller:

```
redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("userName", "Hello, " + someForm.getName() + " nice to meet you.");
```

My thymeleaf

```
<p class="text-danger" th:text="${userName}">userName</p>
```

I know that I can easly use my properties like this:

My message.properties:

> user.name=Tom

My thymeleaf:

```
<a th:text="#{user.name}"></a>
```

But can I reach what I want if there is a value inside?

> My user.name=Hello, {name} nice to meet you.

I would like probably do something like this:

in my controller just:

```
redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("userName", someForm.getName());
```

and in my thymeleaf:

```
<a th:text="#{user.name(name=${userName})}"></a>
```

Is that even possible? How finally should thymeleaf looks like in case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property value like following:

```
user.name=Hello, {0} nice to meet you.
```

And then pass userName like below:

```
<a th:text="#{user.name(${userName})}"></a>
```

The rule is you can add add multiple variables in your property using`{0}, {1}, {2}, .... {n}`.  And you can pass values like `th:text="#{user.name(${param0},${param1},${param2}, ..., ${paramN} )}"`